# why would an interface have properties in them

Tags: c#, .net

why would an interface have a property in it?  I understand that an interface is a contract but why would you ever need a property within an interface?
many thanks

Comment: Because instead of having a method to know (for example) what the count of items in a list, you can have something that looks more convenient + can be more efficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well let's suppose the interface represents a collection of objects.

Further suppose we want to know how many objects.

**Tada!** We use a property `int Count {get;}`

Technically, you never *need* a property because you can always write a `SetX()` and a `GetX()` method. So it's kind of true to say that you would never *need* one.

However, some frameworks use reflection to find properties, especially those frameworks that do serialization and deserialization. In those cases, properties really *are* needed.

In practical terms, properties are often much more readable than methods, and used properly they should convey additional information such as "it is not going to be expensive to read this value" and "reading this value will not cause observable side-effects". (Both those should apply to properly implemented property getters.)

Comment: Example: `IList` or `ICollection`.

Comment: thanks (everyone) for the quick replies!

Comment: Properties can't be used for serialization.  In order to properly capture state of an object, you should go for it's fields.  Serialization libraries don't call methods (setX) but do directly set private members of the objects to restore it to previous state.  If it should use properties, all kind of problems will present itself.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor That's not true. If you write a test class and mark it as `[Serializable]` and put `Console.WriteLine()` into the setters and getters of its properties and then serialize and deserialize it, you will see the setters and getters are being called. Other serializers work differently, but some use the properties.

Comment: I'm glad you pointed out that fact.  That is true for XML serialization, that goes after PUBLIC properties.  It will hold for only simple objects that are data holders, and won't work for anything more complicated.  I guess that you can envision scenario in which that method of de-serialization fails miserably if some setters actually DO something and are called in wrong order...

Comment: @DanielMošmondor I agree, and I use DataContract instead of the older serializers because it makes it easier to handle things correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Properties are shortcuts for `GetSomething()`/`SetSomething()` methods, and those methods are very common in 'contracts' we call interfaces.

Don't mistake properties for fields (public member variables) - properties USUALLY represent behavior of some kind, and if you present that behavior in an interface, you can either put simple backing field or something more complicated in your implementation class.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance No you can't.

Comment: My fault, sorry, I haven't implemented any fields in an interface for a while.

Answer (score 1):

It's just for convenience. Properties are designed as a replacement for getters and setters (methods like `getSomething` and `setSomething`).

For example, we can rewrite this java-code:

```
interface Foo
{
    Bar getBar();
    void setBar(Bar bar);
}
```

...in C# as:

```
interface Foo
{
    Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Yes, you put get/set in an interface. It means interface expects implementing class to implement both getter and setter.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: Reading slightly between the lines of the original question, the OP implied that he/she is familiar with interfaces that contain methods - as is the case in Java, for example. Hence, a comparison of a language that has only methods in interfaces and a language that allows properties in interfaces seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

because things have common properties.

How each class implements their property is up to them.  Some could use Auto Properties, some could query databases.

Answer (score 0):

Properties (`get` and/or `set`), events (`add` and `remove`), and indexers (`get` and/or `set`) all consist of one or two accessors each. An accessor is almost like a method, it just belongs to a more specialized type member.

Quoting from MSDN [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx):

> An interface contains definitions for a group of related functionalities
>   that a class or a struct can implement.[...]
>
> [...]
>
> Interfaces can contain methods, properties, events, indexers, or any
>   combination of those four member types.[...]

I suppose you start reading the above reference.